# Wrapping numbers into quotes using sed / grep

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I'm trying to wrap integers into quotes in a SQL file. The dumped SQL contains an integer column that I would like to convert to string, since it truncates the leading zero for zip codes.

How do I know the zero has been truncated? All zip codes should be 5 characters. The ones that have 4 have the leading zero truncated. For example:

```
INSERT INTO cities VALUES(21919,'MD','Maryland','Earleville',39.427105,-75.94031);
INSERT INTO cities VALUES(21921,'MD','Maryland','Elkton',39.626434,-75.84584);
INSERT INTO cities VALUES(1001,'MA','Massachusetts','Agawam',42.070206,-72.622739);
INSERT INTO cities VALUES(1002,'MA','Massachusetts','Cushman',42.377017,-72.51565);
```

Wanted result:

```
INSERT INTO cities VALUES('21919','MD','Maryland','Earleville',39.427105,-75.94031);
INSERT INTO cities VALUES('21921','MD','Maryland','Elkton',39.626434,-75.84584);
INSERT INTO cities VALUES('01001','MA','Massachusetts','Agawam',42.070206,-72.622739);
INSERT INTO cities VALUES('01002','MA','Massachusetts','Cushman',42.377017,-72.51565);
```

The first two should simply be wrapped. The other two should have the leading zero added.

Two requirements:

1. Wrap all zip code values into strings
2. Add the leading zero to 4 digit ones.

I was able to get all the 4 digit ones using

```
grep "([[:digit:]]\{4\}," cities.sql
```

Or the pattern

```
\([0-9]{4},
```

but I'm not sure how to either wrap the values into quotes, nor to add the leading zero using sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be sed? If you can use awk, you could do:

```
cat cities.sql | awk -F'[,(]' '{printf "%s('\''%05d'\'',%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu-awk it is pretty simple:

```
awk 'match($0, /^(.+?)(\<[0-9]{4,5})(,.+)$/, a) { 
       printf "%s\047%05d\047%s\n", a[1], a[2], a[3] }' file
INSERT INTO cities VALUES('21919','MD','Maryland','Earleville',39.427105,-75.94031);
INSERT INTO cities VALUES('21921','MD','Maryland','Elkton',39.626434,-75.84584);
INSERT INTO cities VALUES('01001','MA','Massachusetts','Agawam',42.070206,-72.622739);
INSERT INTO cities VALUES('01002','MA','Massachusetts','Cushman',42.377017,-72.51565);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it one after the other: First, add the leading zero, then wrap with single quotes:

```
cat cities.sql \
    | sed -e "s/(\([0-9]\{4\}\)/(0\1/" \
    | sed -e "s/(\([0-9]\{5\}\)/(\'\1\'/" \
    > cities2.sql
```

As you can see, I used the fact that the integers are always preceded by a "(" so that the other numbers are not affected. If this is not always the case, you need to adapt the regex accordingly.

In order to wrap something you can use **grouping** by wrapping the bits you want to extract into \( ... \), then you can reference it chronologically in your replace string with \1, \2 etc.

Best regards,
smuecke